# Accumulating events with a resettable initial value

Tags: haskell, frp, threepenny-gui

I need a function like `accumB`, but I would like the initial value to be a `Behavior` instead of a constant. When the initial value changes, the accumulator should 'reset' and start accumulating from that value. Concretely, for the following code and sequence of events:

```
accumB' :: Behavior a -> Event (a -> a) -> IO (Behavior a)
accumB' (stepper 0 ev) ((+) <$> ev')

ev' -> 1
ev' -> 1
ev -> 5
ev' -> 1
```

`accumB'` should return a step function of values `0, 1, 2, 5, 6`.

Is this possible with the combinators currently available in Threepenny, or does it require support for dynamic switching? (I think the answer is 'no', so I'm currently trying to implement my own `accumB'` in terms of `IORef`s...) And if not, is `accumB'` as described above semantically well-defined, or should I be using an `Event a` for my time-varying initial value instead?

Comment: From a model point of view there isn't a *real* notion of "changes" to a Behavior—they're supposed to be nothing more than functions from `Time -> a`. So under that model, it's not clear that your function makes much sense.

Comment: Right, so a Behavior is continuously changing... I guess if I were only looking at resetting Events based on other Events, I could 'reset' an accumulating Event value by doing `unionWith` with an Event of `const` functions and then calling `accumE` on the result. Thanks, that helped clarify my thoughts.

Comment: Which FRP library does Threepenny-gui or your code use? I can't find one in the Threepenny dependencies: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui

Comment: It has its own FRP code rolled in, see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.4.2.0/docs/Reactive-Threepenny.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As J. Abrahamson pointed out in the comments, a `Behavior` varies continuously in time, so the discrete events that mark changes to a `Behavior` aren't well defined. Here are some alternatives.

#### Change behavior by event

If you are using the [reactive package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive) and are looking at changing `Behavior`s based on `Event`s, then `switcher` has the correct type:

```
switcher :: Behavior a -> Event (Behavior a) -> Behavior a
```

#### Accumulate events with reset

As you mention in the comments, if you want to reset an accumulator on an event to `x`, simply put a `const x` event in the stream. This example uses the [reactive package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive).

```
accumBReset :: a -> Event a -> Event (a -> a) -> Behavior a
accumBReset initial resets changes =
    accumB initial allChanges
        where
            allChanges = (fmap const resets) `mappend` changes
```

#### Reactive

In [Push-pull Functional Reactive Programming](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/), Conal Elliott describes the `Reactive` type, which is analogous to a `Behavior` that only changes at discrete moments in time.

```
data Reactive a = a `Stepper` Event a
newtype Event a = Ev (Future (Reactive a))
```

`Reactive` can be converted into a stream of events marking its changes by deconstructing it and taking the right side of the constructor which is the event that next changes its value

```
changes :: Reactive a -> Event a
changes (_ `Stepper` nextChange) = nextChange
```

Alternatively, we could get all the values of the Reactive, including what it is now and all of its future changes

```
values :: Reactive a -> Event a
values = Ev . pure
```

`Reactive` values are in `FRP.Reactive.Reactive` in the [reactive package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive).

#### Get changes from a Behavior at a lower level

In some FRP libraries, you can do more at a lower level. In [reactive-banana](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana) you can observe `changes` to a `Behavior` when making your own `Framework`. Here's the type for  `Reactive.Banana.Framework`'s `changes`

```
changes :: Frameworks t => Behavior t a -> Moment t (Event t (Future a))
```

The documentation warns that this isn't really meaningful:

> Output, observe when a `Behavior` changes.
>
> Strictly speaking, a `Behavior` denotes a value that varies *continuously*
>   in time, so there is no well-defined event which indicates when the
>   behavior changes.
>
> Still, for reasons of efficiency, the library provides a way to
>   observe changes when the behavior is a step function, for instance as
>   created by `stepper`. There are no formal guarantees, but the idea is
>   that
>
> `changes (stepper x e) = return (calm e)`
>
> Note: The values of the event
>   will not become available until event processing is complete. It can
>   be used only in the context of `reactimate'`.